# Run InAppBrowser (or simulate it) in PC browser when using `ionic serve` or `npm run browser` commands

Tags: debugging, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am developing ionic app. In my app, I have InAppBrowser. When I execute `ionic serve` or `npm run browser` the following error appears:
`Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open.`

And after that, new tab opens in chrome browser and nothing happens! Is there any solution except run in emulator (because debugging is very slow and hard with emulator)?

Comment: Have you add `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin ?

Comment: @bhagwattupe yes, I added it and it works fine in device and emulator, but not properly in _chrome browser_!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the browser platform. To build for browser, try something like following -

`ionic cordova build browser`

This will build the browser flavour of ionic.

Note- Add the browser platform.